# What is the meaning of the word "stirring" when used in context with "starch"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am trying to understand this sentence, but just using a dictionary is not helpful:

> Prepared by treating starch with acetic acid anhydride and adipinic acid anhydride. This results in a starch that is resistant against stirring and high temperatures.

I am interested in the word "stirring". What does this sentence actually say the starch is resistant against?

Comment: @WillHunting Incidentally, this is a question on English itself rather than chemistry. The context is a bit of a diversion!

Comment: +1 : when I first read the sentance I thought that the starch would "resist stirring" by being so stiff. I had to had to read Kris's answer to realise what the sentence meant.

Comment: Why would *stirring* mean anything other than *stirring*? As it reads, I could only interpret *stirring* to mean *stirring*.

Comment: @cindi: Ditto. Apparently Kris is something of a chemist. This isn't "general reference" at all - we're dealing with a highly domain-specific sense of *resistant against stirring*. If it should have been closed at all, the only justifiable reason must surely be "too localised".

Comment: Vote Reopen : Agree with @FumbleFingers The comments indicate that the people closing didn't try to understand the question. What are the odds? The dictionary meaning of 'stirring' is irrelevant in this case. –

Comment: @cindi: Ditto (again!). I *might* have voted "too localised" instead of answering, if I'd known at the time that there *was* a "specialised meaning in the context of materials science". But now I'm just irritated by what seems to me to be a case of overenthusiastic "close-happy" voters.

Comment: @cindi Exactly. As a non-native English speaking person, I have problem understanding stirring in this context. I know the verb 'stir' in context e.g.: When I am cooking I have to stir milk on the stove. This meaning applies when "I am stirring something". But my question is about "starch beeing resistant stirring". Does that mean it is so stiff I can not stir it ? How would native speaking person understand this ? Is it possible to say quoted sentence in my question in other words to give it more explaining meaning, please ?

Comment: @Frodik: In this context, as Kris explains in his comment to my answer, *resistant against stirring* has nothing to do with being *difficult to stir*. It simply means that stirring it will not ruin the carefully-designed qualities of the product.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thumbs up for finaly clearing things up. Thanks everyone for effort, I appreciate it !

Comment: @WillHunting: Also, onomato, Matt, Mitch, Kiam, and all friends who 'think otherwise': Could someone please post **ONE reference/link** that provides a **straightforward answer** to the OP? That will set the matter at rest for once and ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Stirring* here means exactly as it is understood in general English.

The starch is not liable to break down or otherwise become ineffective when the product is (vigorously) stirred, as also when exposed to higher temperatures.

---

[Edit-1]
For general clarification: 'Stirring' is one of the standard unit operations in chemical processing. Also, it mimics the activity of stirring as part of cooking in food preparation. Starches are important both in Food Technology as well as the broader chemical process industry where it is properly known as 'agitation' (=stirring, not shaking as may be commonly interpreted), 'mixing' (more than one constituent), etc.

Comment: "Cross linking improves process tolerance, which means the starch can withstand heating, acid ingredients, *stirring*, pumping and packing. This starch does not break down during cooking."[¹](http://www.food-info.net/uk/carbs/starch.htm "Food-Info.net")

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought OP's sentence was badly-formed.

> *resistant against high temperatures* means *able to withstand high temperatures [without degrading]*.

...and without specialised knowledge of the "materials science" context,

> *resistant against stirring* would ordinarily mean *difficult to stir (by virtue of being viscous/thick).*

Those two meanings involve very different roles for the term *resistant against* (like saying *"I made haste and jam"* to mean you made the jam quickly), which would be poor use of language.

---

BUT, per @Kris's answer and various comments, starch formulations may be *degraded* by stirring. Thus, in this particular context, *resistant against stirring* doesn't mean *difficult to stir* - it means *not adversely affected by stirring*.

Note that in more familiar "ability to withstand xxxx" contexts, we often encounter expressions like *heat-resistant, frost-resistant,* etc. However, given that Google Books records [not a single instance](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22stirring%20resistant%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=%22stirring-resistant%22&pbx=1&oq=%22stirring-resistant%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=6480l6766l0l7098l2l2l0l0l0l0l125l205l1.1l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=5cc1ae9b34eaacd8&biw=1269&bih=764) of *stirring-resistant*, I don't think OP should feel too crestfallen at not having understood the usage.

Comment: Stirring is a recognized method by which the physical properties of a material can be modified. Unstable starches possibly breakdown and lose their binding property when stirred (as part of food preparation, in the process of cooking; in an agitator as part of a chemical process ...).

Comment: @Kris: oic. well in that case I think the question should have been closed as "too localised" rather than "general reference".

Comment: Funny! If I use a common English word in my specialized field, it becomes a localized word? Even though it still means exactly the same thing? That is overselling the point!

Comment: @Kris: Well obviously it's not the actual meaning of the word "stirring" that's at issue here. It's the meaning of the phrase *resistant against stirring*, which in most normal contexts would obviously be likely to mean *mechanical resistance* (viscosity, or whatever that funny thing is called when a starch/water mixture stiffens against sudden shocks, but flows easily with slower forces).

Comment: True, generally speaking, your argument holds well enough. However, in the technical context, *resistant* simply means 'withstands', or more specifically, 'does not change its properties/ behavior', as in *heat-resistant*. A heat-resistant material does not prevent you from heating it, rather, it ignores the heating and continues to behave the same way as if nothing happened!

Comment: @Kris: Much the same applies to *crease-resistant* material, for example, which we all know perfectly well isn't something so stiff you can't fold it. Or *frost-resistant* flower pots, which are as likely as ordinary ones to be covered in frost on a cold morning. But to understand these usages you need to know something about the real world, not just how language works. Without the relevant knowledge, *resistant against stirring* means "viscous". I (and OP) now know better, but as the Q is closed, no new answer can be submitted - so I'll change my answer to clarify where the confusion arose.

Comment: True. You'll not find it because the term 'stirring-resistant' is not too technical. It's typically 'resistant to stirring'.

Comment: @Kris: Now we're just going round in circles. You say it doesn't exist as *stirring-resistant* because in technical literature they say *resistant to/against stirring*. I say that to a non-savvy reader, that can only have the obvious meaning of being difficult to stir. Note that Google books records no instances of *"against"*. But of 8 legible instances for *resistant to stirring* 4 are obviously for the "thick/viscous" meaning, 2-3 for this current "polymer dimer/trimer" context, and 1-2 indeterminate (to me - like I said, I'm not a chemist).

Comment: We're on the same page. (Even I am not 'something of a chemist,' as Cindi presumes, only a design consultant for process equipment). In the context of general literature, esp., food preparation, it means 'too thick to stir', yes. However, in tech., it has a set meaning and usually goes without explanation. [cf. - stable gel structure, resistant to stirring: www.creationscouleurs.com/as/as_creagelcrystal_web.pdf p.1 of 2]. Context is everything! :)